# How to paginate requests for large data sets in OData from PowerQuery?

Tags: pagination, odata, powerpivot, powerquery

I have an OData feed that contains a number of large tables (tens of millions of rows).  I need to configure PowerQuery (or PowerPivot, whichever is the best tool for the job) to access this OData feed, but to do so in a paginated way so that a single request doesn't try to return 10 million rows all at once, but instead builds up the complete result of tens of millions of rows with multiple paginated queries.  I don't want to have to manually submit many different URLs with different values of $top and $skip to do my own manual pagination, instead I need PowerQuery or PowerPivot to handle the pagination for me.

I was hoping that PQ/PP would just be smart enough to do pagination, perhaps by first issuing a "count" query to determine how many rows are present, but this appears not to be the case.  When I give PQ/PP a URL to a large OData table, it just blindly issues a query to retrieve all rows (actually, it issues 2 such identical queries, which seems odd), which crashes the DB on the server.

In searching for an answer, I've seen hints that PQ/PP can do pagination, but no clue as to how to enable this behavior.  So is there a way to tell PQ/PP to use some kind of pagination to access large data sets?  If so, can I set the page size?

Comment: Our assumption is that the server will pick the optimal page size, so we largely let the server choose the paging strategy. I believe Sam's answer would be the way to enable this on the server for Web API, though for most applications, I'd probably encourage you to pick a page size larger than 10 :D.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the PageSize on the EnableQueryAttribute if you are using Web API.

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 10)]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
  return Ok(customers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to fetch and append successive pages. Each successive fetch uses a higher "start" line number in the url. And the recursion ends if the fetch yields an empty list. In "M" the if statement can check for empty list otherwise append and increment then "@" to self reference your current function name.